# Why is the CopyConstructor called using Lambdas / Closures?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, closures, copy-constructor

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

struct C {
    explicit C() {std::cout << "constructor" << std::endl; }
    C (const C&) { std::cout << "copyconstructor" << std::endl;}
    ~C() { std::cout << "destructor" << std::endl; }
};

int main(){
    C c1;
    auto f = [c1](){c1;};
    std::cout << "leaving function scope" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with

```
g++ -o a -std=c++11 test.cpp -fno-elide-constructors
```

generates the output:

`constructor
copyconstructor
copyconstructor
destructor
leaving function scope
destructor
destructor`

Compiling with

```
g++ -o a -std=c++11 test.cpp
```

generate the output:

`constructor
copyconstructor
leaving function scope
destructor
destructor`

Since I skipped the `-fno-elide-constructors` compiler option in the second compilation, why did the generated code still call the CopyConstructor once?  I suggested that `g++` compiler would automatically use copy elision for the initialization of `auto f` as it did for initializing the closure, which would have result in:

`constructor
construtor
leaving function scope
destructor
destructor`

Comment: `-fno-elide-constructors` is not an optimization. It is the opposite.

Comment: You're asking the compiler to make a copy of `c1` when you capture it in the lambda, what do you expect it to do in that case?

Comment: `f` is a copy of `c1`, so there has to be at least one copy involved.

Comment: In c++14, you may do `auto f = [c1 = C()](){};` to have your expected result. [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/34f3f084c1080848)

Comment: @Jarod42: If `C` is a trivial type, then `C()` will value initialize it, whereas `c1` in the outer scope is uninitialized. So it's not quite the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I suggested that g++ compiler would automatically use copy elision for the initialization of auto f as it did for initializing the closure

But it did not use copy elision for initializing the closure. The lone `copyconstructor` you saw *was* the initialization of the closure's variable. That cannot be elided away. Even in C++17; you will always have 2 C objects, one copied from the other.

If you wanted the lambda to merely reference the outer scope, then you should have captured the variable by reference: `[&c1]`. Capturing by value means copying it.

Comment: But why did it print 2 times `copyconstructor` when I used the `-fno-elide-constructors` option?

Comment: @SebTu: Because `auto f = prvalue`, in pre C++17, means to generate that prvalue temporary and use it to initialize `f`. So it will do a copy/move, unless it is elided. And you stopped the elision of it with that option.